# Printindex wihin KOMA script class without declare deprecated commands like \bf

Tags: koma-script, makeindex, undefined

I'm using the document class scrartcl and want to have an index. This worked fine in the previous years using this source:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{showidx}


\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{Text}
Here is a Term\index{Term}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

However, recently I got the error:

```
(./index.ind [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

! Class scrartcl Error: undefined old font command `\bf'.

See the scrartcl class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2 {\bf
         B}\nopagebreak%
? ^C! Interruption.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \endgroup 
l.2 {\bf
         B}\nopagebreak%
```

I know that declare the missing command fix the error:

> \DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}

Obviously I'm using some outdated way to generate an index, so my question is how to generate an index within KOMA script class without declare old deprecated commands?

Comment: Strangely enough, if I correct the missing `\` before `documentclass` and run pdflatex/makeindex/pdflatex on your example document above, I don't get the error message you reported. There must be something you don't show. Neither `makeidx` nor `scrartcl` uses `\bf` any longer

Comment: Side note: You have some answers to your questions, but accepted none. Please consider to accept them in order to show your appreciation of the help provided by TeX.SE users

Comment: you are using a non standard makeindex style?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Christian Hupfer and David Carlisle!

Indeed, the Makefile called `makeindex` with the `-s` parameter and referred to an style file which was unknown for me. Within the style file the `\bf` command was used. After replacing that, it works as expected. Thank you very much for your help!